# How to put commas in numbers without using to_char?

Tags: oracle, formatting, numbers

I have variable defined as `NUMBER` type and it has values like `2314514512` how can I add comma to this number so that it appears like `2,314,514,512` without using `to_char`?

Comment: You'd do that somewhere in the code that displays the number to a user, and not in the database. What language/environment/etc. are you using to display the data ?

Comment: It has to be done in the client application. Oracle doesn't store formats in the data dictionary like some RDBMS do. What are you using, Sql Plus, java, an IDE?

Comment: @nos - This is related to report am working on. I am making call to pipelined functions which returns me back the data. There is not much code involed. I am using Reporting Tool for generating reports.

Comment: @redcayuga - I am using Oracle SQL Developer and as mentioned in my previous comment am using Reporting Tool for generation of report which makes call to function and function returns the value back which is displayed back to the user.

Comment: Do the format in Reporting Tool.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to solve the issue as I did formatting part from the reporting tool before rendering data back to the user.